# (C# Jagged Arrays) Howcome my jagged array counts normally, and not in elements?

Tags: c#, counting, jagged-arrays

In the code below, I am confused about why the line `int[,][] jaggedArr = new int [ 2, 3 ] [];`
requires to be counted normally, and not in elements like coders would practice.

I initially input it as `int[,][] jaggedArr = new int [ 1, 2 ] [];`, but wouldnt work.

Can someone please explain why this is so?

```
class JaggedArrays
{            
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        int[,][] jaggedArr = new int[2, 3][];

        jaggedArr[0, 0] = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        jaggedArr[0, 1] = new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        jaggedArr[0, 2] = new int[] { 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};

        jaggedArr[1, 0] = new int[] { 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };
        jaggedArr[1, 1] = new int[] { 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 };
        jaggedArr[1, 2] = new int[] { 25, 26, 27 };

        Console.WriteLine(jaggedArr[0, 2][2]);
        Console.WriteLine(jaggedArr.Length);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You "initially" input is creating a two dimensional array with one (1) entry (see it as row), which has (2) elements (imagine as columns). And you should keep in mind: C# uses 0 based arrays. So the creation of an array with [1] element allows only index 0. Other simple method to think about it: Your highest available index is 1 less then length of array.

Comment: The code works as I expect. It's possible that you look for a function like `jaggedArr.GetLength(0)` to ask for the count of the first dimension?